# Query calling array instead of type 'object'

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I'm not sure why the following query has stopped working. Basically we have listener location and pastlistenerlocation and it seems our pastlistenerlocation does not want to update.

```
BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'",
```

The query I am running is:

```
db.getCollection("pastlistenerslocation").updateMany(
  { "location.coordinates": { $exists: true } },
  [{
    $set: {
      "location.coordinates": [
        { 
          $toDouble: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$location.coordinates", 0]
          }
        },
        { 
          $toDouble: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$location.coordinates", 1]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
)
```

My data looks like

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b5f1fe0948ad2d50428b48"), 
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            "115.88027251449634", 
            "-31.925607553334974"
        ]
    }, 
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2021-06-01T08:38:21.212+0000")
}
```

I am using Mongodb version 4.0.3.

Comment: Updates with Aggregation Pipeline requires MongoDB v 4.2 or later.

Comment: @prasad_ Just updated to 5.0.2 and running query again.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to updateMany is an array: MongoDB is expecting it to be an object.